# Calling Fortran from C# in VS2019 with iFort

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to call Fortran code from C#. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and the Intel Fortran Compiler (iFort).

I created a fortran DLL project with the following code that compiles without issue (project set to 'release', 'x64'):

```
module Fortran_DLL_Lib
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine adder(a,b,x,y)
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:'adder' :: adder
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: x,y
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: a,b
        integer, intent(out) :: x,y
        y = a + b
        x = 2*a+3*b
    end subroutine
end module
```

I then created a C# console application with the following code (project also set to 'Release', 'x64'):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Call_Fortran_Dll_FromCS_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Fortran_DLL_Lib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void adder(int a, int b, [Out] int x, [Out] int y);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 4;
            int b = 3;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);

            adder(a, b, x, y); //error occurs here
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine(y);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The program runs up until the line that calls the fortran function, then returns the error

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Call_Fortran_Dll_FromCS_Test.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Call_Fortran_Dll_FromCS_Test.dll
Unable to load DLL 'Fortran_DLL_Lib.dll' or one of its dependencies: Access is denied. (0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I have copied both the 'Fortran_DLL_Lib.dll' and 'Fortran_DLL_Lib.lib' files into both the folder that contains the c# project files, as well as the location where the executable project is located, neither seems to help/matter.

This is just based on example code I found trying to find ways to do this and isn't specific to what I'm doing. I'm just trying to get a 'proof of concept' together before jumping into more complex applications. The solution doesn't even necessarily be a DLL, that's just what I saw people recommending as the solution to this (in 7+ year old questions on this site). Open to any solutions that successfully call Fortran code from a C# project (eventually, a C# project with a WPF GUI, if that matters).

I am in a situation where I can't install Dependency Walker, change environment variables, or pretty much anything that requires elevated privileges.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: The very thorough and detailed answer by @JAlex below works perfectly, for both .NET Framework and .NET Core. My ongoing issues are due to user account policies at my workplace that prevent running *.dll files (apparently). Trying the solution on a normal, un-restricted system worked perfectly without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the `dll` is next to the C# driver binary, add the dll into the CSharp solution. Use add-existing and **then add as link**

[image: fig2]

then select the link in the solution and set to copy if newer

[image: fig3]

this will place the dll in the output folder

[image: fig4]

additionally, I set the calling convention in Fortran as CVF, although I think this is optional as I specify explicitly which argument is `REFERENCE` and which is `VALUE`.

[image: fig5]

I checked the DLL export using `dumpbin /exports`

[image: fig6]

The following code works as indented:

#### Fortran Project

Note the addition of the `VALUE` attributes as well as the `REFERENCE` ones.

```
module mod_Fortran_dll
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
contains
    subroutine adder(a,b,x,y)
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, alias:'adder' :: adder
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: a,b
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: x,y
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: a,b
        integer, intent(out) :: x,y
        y = a + b
        x = 2*a+3*b
    end subroutine
end module
```

#### CSharp Project

Note the removal of the `CDecl` calling convention, and the specific `EntryPoint` specification.

```
static class Program
{
    #region Fortran
    [DllImport("FortranLib.dll", EntryPoint = "adder")]
    public static extern void adder(int a, int b, [Out] out int x, [Out] out int y);

    #endregion
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 4;
        int b = 3;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        Console.WriteLine($"a={a}, b={b}, x={x}, y={y}");
        // a = 4, b = 3, x = 0, y = 0

        adder(a, b, out x, out y);

        Console.WriteLine($"a={a}, b={b}, x={x}, y={y}");
        // a = 4, b = 3, x = 17, y = 7
    }
}
```

Note that the  `[Out]` attribute is *required* for structure types, but not for primitive types.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info @JAlex! Unfortunately, that doesn't fix the issue that I am seeing.

Comment: @CoderJoe1991 - let me work out an example for you. Also look at the edit in the post on how to make sure the fortran dll follows the csharp binary.

Comment: thanks again for the responses. I followed the steps you described and am still getting the same error. I also tried adding the DLL project as a second project in the solution (as it appears you did in your second image) and that also didn't help.

Comment: @CoderJoe1991 - follow the step I posted right now. The connection to the DLL works for me giving me the results posted on the csharp code comments main program.

Comment: I have followed the steps you have posted other than dumpbin, which my command prompt just tells me isn't recognized as an internal or external command (if this should be run elsewhere let me know). I copied your code changes into my projects and am still seeing the same error. My guess is it's somehow not picking up the dependencies from iFort that it needs, because the DLL is there, and it's being copied to the output/compile folder successfully.

Comment: I also tried starting over with new projects and just copy-pasting your code and following the steps, leaving the settings for the projects as the default 'Debug' 'x86' for the Fortran project, and 'Debug' 'Any CPU' for the C# Project. Still same error message

Comment: I figured out how to run dumpbin /exports and it shows ordinal hint RVA name, 1 0 00001039 adder = adder

Comment: The only other thing I can see that is different is that your path to your output folder is ..bin\x64\Release, whereas mine is ..bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1. Could that have something to do with it @JAlex

Comment: I was using a .NET Framework console and not a .NET Core console. I will port over and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: I switched over and made a new project using .NET Framework instead and am now getting a different error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in FrameworkDllTest.exe
Unable to load DLL 'FortDllTest.dll': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" Which...I feel like is better. Will try to reboot my machine just in case something weird with permissions is going on that's causing the new error.

Comment: @CoderJoe1991 - you can [check out my code](https://github.com/johnalx/FortranDll_CSharp) on GitHub. The next step is to try to marshal arrays, which I did with the `fill_curve` procedure in the posted code.

Comment: I downloaded your code from github, opened the project, re-added the dll since it was giving an error about the path being different, and am still getting the 'Access is denied' error. Makes me wonder if theres some stupid permissions thing here at work that doesn't like loading dll files. I'll give it a try at home on a non-restricted computer and see if I get the same errors and report back tomorrow. Thanks again for all the help @JAlex!

Comment: Worth reading [this article](https://devopsonwindows.com/handle-platform-specific-dependencies/) on how to handle platform dependencies.

Comment: Why does the Fortran source have `use iso_c_binding` when nothing from that module is referenced?

Comment: @francescalus just how my templates are setup. Actually I do use `c_double` for `fill_curve` and should use `c_int` instead of just `integer`. I did notice the configuration manager needs to be used to set all to `x64` before compiling the fortran and then the csharp for my _link_ to the dll to work. I was able to confirm that just downloading the code from GH into a new computer, setting to `Debug/x64`, and compiling is all that is required to make it work.

Comment: @JAlex - your solution works perfectly on my home computer, so it must be some nonsense with user policies here at work. Thank you again so much for your help and very thorough answer!